# What are the applications of spin geometry?

Tags: big-list, spin-geometry, spinor, gravity-theory

What are applications of spin geometry to physics? Does it have something to do with gravity?

Comment: Applications to what? Math? Physics? Chemistry?

Comment: Applications to physics.

Answer (score 3):

I understand the question as requesting applications of the geometry of spin manifolds outside of pure mathematics. There are many, starting with the Dirac equation for the spinor of a relativistic electron (1920). Recent applications center on topological states of matter and on quantum theories of gravity.

One recent overview is given in
[Spin Geometry and Some Applications](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.06988).

For an application beyond physics, see [Spin Geometry and Image Processing.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260225057_Spin_Geometry_and_Image_Processing)

Comment: Thank you very much.